# How to stop XCode to do NSLog it self?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimage, nsurlconnection, nslog

I'm using `NSURLConnection` to load an image (of size 1.2 mb) from server. What I'm doing is in `delegate` I'm assigning my `imageView` (its an `UIImageView`) with received image. So it looks like downloading.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:receivedData];
    imageView.image = image;
    image = nil;
}
```

During the time XCode prints `NSLog` with the following message.

> ```
> <Error>: ImageIO: JPEG Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment
> ```

I know its the message of corruted bytes i'm making an `UIImage` and then assing it to `imageView`.

**Is there anyway to stop XCode to write this message on behalf of me?** *I've to do so as I need to show user that image is downloading.*

I've checked some answers that on checking `bytes`!! But its not my solution as I already know why this happens?, I just want to stop XCode to print this on be half of me.

**Edited**

Data would corrupted while Downloading using of NSURLConnection.

Thanks!

Comment: What's printing here in NSLog ? Is it Image ? its seems very lack question..

Comment: So image appears partly? Like in the old times with slow internet connection, images appeared line by line?
Not sure why are you doing it like that, it's better to rely on `connectionDidFinishLoading` an show activity indicator instead.

Comment: @MANIAK_dobrii, Good `comment` answer! What if there will be 50 of images can be load at the same time, and I don't just relay on `UIActivityIndicator` and `progressCounter` as I'm already doing so. I want to make it friendly that user get attention that `yes, images are coming!! :)`.

Comment: Btw it only shows the nslog while you test it on simulator on real device does it run well? if yes why you bother about the nslogs ? It will never noted by any app user on device lol :)

Comment: @Wolvorin, :D Yes that's I can feel, that `no-user` will get so!! But when I run it in device it still prints it. You know as developer a single message would jump us on our chair!!! :D

Comment: I think there is no other way or workaround for this as described in below answers :) And if you found one I am eager to test it. Please post it here for us :)

Comment: Of course, I'll. I would accept the answer from @Prince but I'm looking for the exact solution if its possible.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** If u have more images then its better u use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for loading images

Firstly recieve whole data of image for that use this delegates:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    if (!receivedData)
    {
        receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
    }

    [receivedData appendData:data];

    NSLog(@"Receiving data... Length: %d", [receivedData length]);
}
```

Now data received completely this method will be called:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:receivedData];
  if(image) 
    imageView.image = image;
}
```

Comment: `I know this thing, but I can't implement in that way! Read question again.`

Comment: Read the answer again. You're trying to make the image before you've downloaded it all, this is always going to give you an error. Use a progress view or activity indicator to show that your download is progressing.

Comment: I'm already did this before. What if there will be 50 of images can be load at the same time, and I don't just relay on `UIActivityIndicator` and `progressCounter` as I'm already doing so. I want to make it friendly that user get attention that `yes, images are coming!! :)`.